Primes represented by forms of the same discriminants
Let $p$ be a prime number which is represented by forms $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ of the same discriminant. Show that $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ are equivalent.
I have proved a lemma that $p$ is properly represented by $f(x,y)$ if and only if $f(x,y)$ is properly equivalent to the form $$px^2+Bxy+Cy^2 \qquad \text{for} \qquad B,C \in \mathbb{Z},$$and I believe this is the key to solve this problem, but I am confused about how to improve properly equivalent to equivalent.

Can you please provide some numerical examples?

By your quoted result we may assume that $f(x,y)=px^2+Bxy+Cy^2$ and $g(x,y)=px^2+B'xy+C'y^2$. That they have the same discrimant means $B^2-4pC=B'^2-4pC'$. We want to show here exist $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb Z$ with $ad-bc=\pm1$ and $f(ax+by,cx+dy)=g(x,y)$. We have $$f(ax+by,cx+dy)=(pa^2+acB+Cc^2)x^2 + (2abp+(bc+ad)B+2cdC)xy + (b^2p+bdB+d^2C)y^2.$$
Let's take $a=1, c=0$, then $d=\pm1$ and this simplifies to $$px^2+(2bp+dB)xy + (b^2p+bdB+C)y^2.$$
So we want $2bp+dB = B'$ and $b^2p+bdB+C = C'$. From $B^2-4pC=B'^2-4pC'$ we get $B\equiv\pm B'\pmod {2p}$ (distinguish the cases $p=2$ and $p\ne2$), so there exist $d=\pm1$ and $b\in\Bbb Z$ such that $2bp+dB=B'$. Squaring this and simplifying gives $b^2p+bdB+C=C'$.
